# Como testar conexão com banco SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, conexão

Tenho uma aplicação que se conecta ao SQL Server, porém em um terminal de um cliente esta retornando um erro aleatório.

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu testar a conexão desse terminal com o servidor SQLServer, de forma isolada da minha aplicação. E se possivel fazer uma consulta.

Quando o banco é oracle consigo fazer isso com o TNSPing e SQLPlus, mas não sei como testar com o SQLServer.

Está pingando no servidor do banco, único teste que consegui fazer.

S.O.: Windows 10

Comment: Você pode fazer um teste com Telnet, Udl, ou se possuir as ferramentas de client do sql server instaladas você pode tentar com sqlcmd

Comment: Não tem cliente do sqlserver instalado nesse terminal, telnet e sqlcmd não funciona.. agora vi na resposta que tem esse udl.. vou testar. Obrigado

Comment: Você tem que considerar algumas coisas, por padrão o SQL Express vem com conexão remota desabilitado então se for você tem que habilitar, e no caso de outras versão você tem que verificar a porta 1433.

Comment: Então, o erro é e um terminal somente, os outros estão funcionando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie um novo arquivo txt em branco no computador que gostaria de realizar o teste:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E depois altere sua extensão para .udl:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Execute este arquivo e você poderá testar a conexão com a base de dados:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deu certo, Obrigado !

Comment: Apenas uma observação em relação a segurança. Os arquivos .udl quando editados exibem informações sobre a conexão então todo cuidado se for mante-lo salvo.